# Axios api call gives Network error while fetch() works well

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm a react native beginner. I'm trying to make a simple http get request using axios.

Here is my axios configuration:

```
import axios from 'axios';

    export default axios.create({
     baseUrl: 'https://blobrfishwebapi.azurewebsites.net',
    });
```

And this is how I make the request using my configured axios:

```
import configuredAxios '../api/configuredAxios';

     const response = await configuredAxios 
          .get('/employer/jobposts/recenttest')
          .then(res => res.data)
          .then(({data, isSuccessful, message}) => {
            if (!isSuccessful) {
              throw new Error(message);
            }
            setjobPostings(data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(err, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err)));
          });
```

This is the error I get when I make the above call:

```
{"stack":"Error: **Network Error**\n    at createError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.blobfshemployer&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:98386:17)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.blobfshemployer&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:98196:69)\n.....
```

Finally, same endpoint call using fetch() which returns a 200 status code:

```
let response = await fetch(
 'https://blobrfishwebapi.azurewebsites.net/employer/jobposts/recenttest',
);
let json = await response.json();
setjobPostings(JSON.stringify(json, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(json)));
catch(
err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err))),
console.log('error'),
);
```

Has anyone experienced a similar problem using axios?
I'm running my app on an android emulator, axios version is 0.21.4, react native version is 0.70.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems your endpoints are not the same for each scenario. You are fetching '/employer/jobposts' using axios where '/employer/jobposts/recenttest' is fetched using fetch.

Comment: @csath thanks for noticing that,I did some tests with other endpoints before asking my question and forgot to reset to original endpoint. However the issue with axios applies to all endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Rookie error! The "baseUrl" property of my axios config object should have the "url" part capitalized:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
 base**URL**: 'https://blobrfishwebapi.azurewebsites.net',
});
```